# Nunjucks variable

Tags: nunjucks, eleventy

I'm using 11ty to render meta tags on different pages. I have a JSON where I have all the data defined.

```
{
  "home": [
    [
      {
        "paramType": "content",
        "paramValue": "Home Page Content"
      },
      {
        "paramType": "name",
        "paramValue": "title"
      }
    ]
  ],
  "about-us": [
    [
      {
        "paramType": "content",
        "paramValue": "Some content"
      },
      {
        "paramType": "name",
        "paramValue": "description"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Now I want to render data on respective pages, the page name is stored in variable page_name

```
{% set page_name = home %}
{% for tag in meta[page_name] %}
    <meta 
    {% for item in tag %} 
        {{ item.paramType }}="{{ item.paramValue }}" 
    {% endfor %}
    >
{% endfor %}
```

meta[page_name] doesn't work but meta.home works, is there a way to make it work for nunjucks ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to access `meta[page_name]`, `page_name` needs to be a string. When you do `{% set page_name = home %}`, you're actually setting `page_name` to the variable `home`, which is not defined.

Changing it to `{% set page_name = "home" %}` (with the double quotes) works as expected.